# SecretKeySpec AES Equivalency of Java Code for C#

Tags: java, asp.net, asp.net-core

Create SecretKey instance using Base64 decoded value and AES algorithm. Here the secret key must be of length 32

This Code is in Java and I need Equivalent for C#

```
        public static SecretKey getSecretKey(String secretKey)
        { 
            byte[] decodeSecretKey = base64Decode(secretKey);
            return new SecretKeySpec(decodeSecretKey, 0, decodeSecretKey.Length, "AES");
        }

        public static byte[] base64Decode(string data)
        {
               return Base64.getDecoder().decode(data);
        }
```

Comment: AFAIK .Net doesn't have a POCO representing the 'Key' and its encoding. What you need to do is to use [`System.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricAlgorithm.Create("AES")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.create?view=net-5.0#System_Security_Cryptography_SymmetricAlgorithm_Create_System_String_) and then set the Key, IV, Padding and Mode accordingly on the resultant `SymmetricAlgorithm` object.

Comment: But Output Varies i tried it in C# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=net-5.0#code-try-2